# Best algorithm to group and add in a list of following pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Let us consider we have objects in a list as

```
listOfObjects = [a,b,ob,ob,c,ob,c,ob,c,ob,ob,c,ob]
```

we have to group them as

```
[ob,ob,c,ob,c,ob] from index 2 to 7
[ob,ob,c,ob] from index 9 to 12
```

i.e the **group starts** if we have **two ob's together**, as in index 2 and 7, and **ends** before the **'c' having two ob's following**, as in index 8 **having 'c' which is followed by two 'ob's** or **if the list ends**.

So what will be the best algorithm to get the above(in java)?

Comment: You're trying to match contiguous patters in a sequence.  This is covered well in the literature.  Please follow the posting guidelines: do your on-line research before posting here.

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "best algorithm" according to you is that which is optimal in terms of time complexity.

You can do this task by simple one traversal with keeping track of next 3 elements (of course taking care that you don't go out of list size) and ending the group by checking the strategy you said. If there are no 3 elements next the current element, you simply end your group (as you specified in your strategy)

So the time complexity of this algorithm will be `O(n)`. It will not be possible to get better than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think Stack is a suitable data structure.

it'll be all right once you put 'ob' in the stack.

also you need 'count' variable.